# Release artifact name and version in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, grgit

I am using the gradle git to release artifacts: https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git. Is it possible to get the release artifact name and version that it uses in the release stage in another stage that runs after release in the Jenkinsfile?